# CUDA: Erroneous lmem statistics displayed for sm_20?

Tags: cuda, nvcc, ptxas

A CUDA kernel compiled with the option `--ptxas-options=-v` seems to be displaying erroneous **lmem (local memory)** statistics when `sm_20` GPU architecture is specified. The same gives meaningful lmem statistics with `sm_10 / sm_11 / sm_12 / sm_13` architectures.

Can someone clarify if the sm_20 lmem statistics need to be read differently or they are plain wrong?

Here is the kernel:

```
__global__ void fooKernel( int* dResult )
{
        const int num = 1000;
        int val[num]; 

        for ( int i = 0; i < num; ++i )
        val[i] = i * i; 

        int result = 0; 

        for ( int i = 0; i < num; ++i )
        result += val[i]; 

        *dResult = result;

        return;
}
```

`--ptxas-options=-v` and `sm_20` report:

```
1>ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z9fooKernelPi' for 'sm_20'
1>ptxas info    : Used 5 registers, 4+0 bytes lmem, 36 bytes cmem[0]
```

`--ptxas-options=-v` and `sm_10 / sm_11 / sm_12 / sm_13` report:

```
1>ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z9fooKernelPi' for 'sm_10'
1>ptxas info    : Used 3 registers, 4000+0 bytes lmem, 4+16 bytes smem, 4 bytes cmem[1]
```

sm_20 reports a lmem of **4 bytes**, which is simply not possible if you see the 4x1000 byte array being used in the kernel. The older GPU architectures report the correct **4000 byte** lmem statistic.

This was tried with **CUDA 3.2**. I have referred to the **Printing Code Generation Statistics** section of the **NVCC manual** (v3.2), but it does not help explain this anomaly.

Comment: possibly different optimization.  show ptx assembly to get what happened.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is correct. Through clever optimization the array doesn't need to be stored. What you do is essentially calculating `result += i * i` without ever storing temporaries to `val`.

A look at the generated ptx code won't show any differences for sm_10 vs. sm_20. Decompiling the generated cubins with decuda will reveal the optimization.

BTW: Try to avoid local memory! It is as slow as global memory.

Comment: Compiler optimization was my first suspicion. But, it still reports 4 bytes (only under sm_20) for kernel code that cannot be optimized away.